# Simple Array Loop Not Working

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to use a standard foreach loop example to read my array and it will not increment...

```
$array = json_decode('{"variants":[{"barcode":"610373772697","compare_at_price":null,"created_at":"2015-06-27T01:56:42-07:00","fulfillment_service":"manual","grams":190,"id":3856358467,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","option1":"Default Title","option2":null,"option3":null,"position":1,"price":"20.99","product_id":1259972867,"requires_shipping":true,"sku":"1125442","taxable":true,"title":"Default Title","updated_at":"2015-06-27T01:56:42-07:00","inventory_quantity":100,"old_inventory_quantity":100,"image_id":null,"weight":0.42,"weight_unit":"lb"},{"barcode":"364031530906","compare_at_price":null,"created_at":"2015-06-27T01:56:42-07:00","fulfillment_service":"manual","grams":131,"id":3856359043,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","option1":"Default Title","option2":null,"option3":null,"position":1,"price":"17.24","product_id":1259973059,"requires_shipping":true,"sku":"0116350","taxable":true,"title":"Default Title","updated_at":"2015-06-27T01:56:42-07:00","inventory_quantity":100,"old_inventory_quantity":100,"image_id":null,"weight":0.29,"weight_unit":"lb"},{"barcode":"364031534003","compare_at_price":null,"created_at":"2015-06-27T01:56:43-07:00","fulfillment_service":"manual","grams":390,"id":3856359107,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","option1":"Default Title","option2":null,"option3":null,"position":1,"price":"27.74","product_id":1259973123,"requires_shipping":true,"sku":"0116368","taxable":true,"title":"Default Title","updated_at":"2015-06-27T01:56:43-07:00","inventory_quantity":100,"old_inventory_quantity":100,"image_id":null,"weight":0.86,"weight_unit":"lb"}]}', true);

foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    print "$key = $val\n";
}
```

Which returns:
"variants = Array"

I can't get it to go deeper into the second level of the array and get the sku and id values.

Answer (score 4):

its a multi dimensional array

try

```
$array = json_decode('{"variants":[{"barcode":"610373772697","compare_at_price":null,"created_at":"2015-06-27T01:56:42-07:00","fulfillment_service":"manual","grams":190,"id":3856358467,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","option1":"Default Title","option2":null,"option3":null,"position":1,"price":"20.99","product_id":1259972867,"requires_shipping":true,"sku":"1125442","taxable":true,"title":"Default Title","updated_at":"2015-06-27T01:56:42-07:00","inventory_quantity":100,"old_inventory_quantity":100,"image_id":null,"weight":0.42,"weight_unit":"lb"},{"barcode":"364031530906","compare_at_price":null,"created_at":"2015-06-27T01:56:42-07:00","fulfillment_service":"manual","grams":131,"id":3856359043,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","option1":"Default Title","option2":null,"option3":null,"position":1,"price":"17.24","product_id":1259973059,"requires_shipping":true,"sku":"0116350","taxable":true,"title":"Default Title","updated_at":"2015-06-27T01:56:42-07:00","inventory_quantity":100,"old_inventory_quantity":100,"image_id":null,"weight":0.29,"weight_unit":"lb"},{"barcode":"364031534003","compare_at_price":null,"created_at":"2015-06-27T01:56:43-07:00","fulfillment_service":"manual","grams":390,"id":3856359107,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","option1":"Default Title","option2":null,"option3":null,"position":1,"price":"27.74","product_id":1259973123,"requires_shipping":true,"sku":"0116368","taxable":true,"title":"Default Title","updated_at":"2015-06-27T01:56:43-07:00","inventory_quantity":100,"old_inventory_quantity":100,"image_id":null,"weight":0.86,"weight_unit":"lb"}]}', true);

    foreach ($array['variants'] as $k=>$v) {
    echo $k."<br><br>";
      foreach ($v as $kk=>$vv){
        echo  $kk .'='. $vv."<br>";
      } 
    }
```

Comment: @Dagon congrats on the PHP gold tag/badge. ;-) *Go get 'em Tigger!*

Comment: @Fred-ii- i have been abusing (er using) it for about a week closing duplicates like a mo-fo

Comment: @Dagon Not like a certain snake who's got no "common sense" ;-) cheers

Answer (score 1):

Use `$array['variants']` in your foreach instead.

Comment: its has more dimensions than that